# When do i need to dispose a (server-client) objects?

Tags: c#, stream, client-server, dispose, idisposable

in server -(multi)client application [TCP]. I use Socket, NetworkStream, StreamReader and StreamWriter for each client i Accept in the server .. so i have couple of questions :

Do i have to dispose all of them when i want to close the connection with a client?

If the client Disposes the Socket that's connected with the server .. do i also have do dispose that socket in the server side ,or it closes automatically ?

in my code here :

```
 Thread thAccept = new Thread(acceptClient);
 Thread thJob;
 private void acceptClient()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Socket client = server.Accept();
            Console.WriteLine(client.RemoteEndPoint+" has connected");
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(new NetworkStream(client));
            //is it ok to create an instance NetworkStream like this or i will have to dispose it later?

            thJob = new Thread(Job);
            thJob.Start(reader);
        }
    }

 private void Job(object o)
    {
        StreamReader reader = (Socket)o;
        try
        {
            string cmd = null;
            while ((cmd = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
              //(BLA BLA..)
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Disconnected by catch");  
        }
        finally
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Finally Done.");
            reader.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

is that code fine to dispose all (needed to be disposed) objects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Proper use of the IDisposable interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/538060/proper-use-of-the-idisposable-interface)

Comment: Please do a little searching before posting a question. This one has been asked a dozen times or more.

Comment: @JohnSaunders well, im still beginner to c# .. i couldn't understand all of the answer of your link.. but i think it doesn't answer my questions .. its kinda a different question .. i dept that you read it to the end .. you just read the subject! there are sub-questions that's important to me .. please if you don't want to help.. let others to help me and don't close my question.

Comment: Ok, you're almost right. I read the title _and_ the text of your question. I did not read the code. This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a duplicate.

Your code differs from the linked duplicate because in your code, the `IDisposable` is handed off to another thread.

The general rule is that if you create an object that implements `IDisposable`, then you're responsible for calling `Dispose` on it when you're finished with it. When possible, that should be done in a `using` block, to ensure that `Dispose` is always called. In your case, your code is not *finished* with the object until the other thread is exited. In that thread, you correctly call `Dispose` in the `finally` block.

If you had called `Dispose` on the `NetworkStream`, then it would have closed the `StreamReader` as well, which would defeat your purpose. I suspect it would be the same thing if you had called `Dispose` on the `Socket`. As such, your code is correct as-is.

The object on the client side has no relationship with the object on the server side, except through TCP/IP. The fact that the client may call `Dispose` on its socket doesn't mean that the server has to call `Dispose` on its socket. However, once the server is finished reading data from the socket, and the connection is closed, the server-side socket should be `Disposed`. I don't know for certain, but I believe that when the `StreamReader` is disposed, the underlying `NetworkStream` will be disposed, which should call `Dispose` on the socket from which the stream was created.

Your code is fine, except for some unrelated issues: you don't need to set `cmd` to `null`, since you're going to set the value in the next statement. Also, you should not use an empty `catch` block like that. You have no idea what exception was thrown, but you will ignore it anyway, without even logging or displaying the exception. At the least, you should do

```
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

        Console.WriteLine("Disconnected by exception " + ex.ToString());   
    } 
    finally 
    {  
        Console.WriteLine("Finally Done."); 
        reader.Dispose(); 
    }
```

Comment: thanks for the answer ...
the code i posted is a draft .. i just put it there to know that the connection closed because of the client. there's no need for it later its a silent server .. user shouldn't notify anything.